# angular d3 not rendering uniquely with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

i am trying to implement **angular-d3-donut** to my web application. each  has one **SVG(donut)**. so if i generate  using *ngFor there'll be multiple  with one SVG(donut). but problem is that, if i try to generate multiple  by *ngFor, **only one  is creating and multiple SVG(donut) nesting inside the single** . so i am getting design mismatching and different result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4]; let myIndex = index">
         <angular-d3-donut  [data]="donutChartData" [outerRadius]=60 [innerRadius]=20 [spreadSlice]=true [iconWidth]=20 [iconHeight]=20 ></angular-d3-donut>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
public donutChartData = [{
        id: 0, // number
        label: 'A',  // string
        value: 70,  // number
        color: '#ccc',  // string,
        iconImage: 'https://avatars.discourse.org/v2/letter/a/a8b319/45.png' // string
    }, {
        id: 1, // number
        label: 'B',  // string
        value: 30,  // number
        color: '#DA4F49',  // string,
        iconImage: 'https://avatars.discourse.org/v2/letter/a/a8b319/45.png' // string
    }
]
```

**Inspected HTML Output**
[image]

Comment: What happens if create the loop manually I.e. if you stack 4 donut charts on your page ? Do you get the same result ?

Comment: @Safiyya creating 4 donut charts, but all donuts inside one <angular-d3-donut>. i need to see four <angular-d3-donut> with single donut as per code snippets.

Comment: I understand. I was trying to see if the issue was in the angular-d3 library or with your Code. Can you recreate this in a stackblitz ?

Comment: @Safiyya , I am also facing similar issue. I want a pie chart on specific position of image but it is not coming https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-git3mo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you are plotting in the same "dountChart" div each time. If you want to create a new div, you need to change the id of each "dountChart". For instance, let's suppose I want to plot multiple circles (your dount charts) so I have this HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of options.items; index as i">
    <angular-d3-donut [index]="i"></angular-d3-donut>
</div>
```

Let's say that `item` is my dummy data. If you pass the index `i` to your `angular-d3-donut` component you can use it to identify your multiple DOM elements

```
@Component
({
    selector: 'angular-d3-donut',
    templateUrl: './angular-d3-donut.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./angular-d3-donut.component.css']
})

export class AngularD3Donut implements OnInit 
{
    private circle: any; // Is Circle class
    private container: any; // div
    @Input() public index: number = 0;
    @Input() public height: number = 20;
    public color: string = 'black';

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
        this.container = d3.select('#dountChart') // First select the original id
            .attr('id', 'dountChart' + this.index) // Now, change the id to make it unique
            .style('height', this.height.toString() + "px")
            .style('background-color', 'red');

        this.circle = new Circle(10, this.color, 10, 10, this.index); // Circle(radius, 'color', coor_x, coor_y, index)
    }
}

class Circle
{
    private container: any; //svg
    private circle: any;

    constructor(private radius: number, private color: string, private x: number, private y: number, private index: number)
    {
        this.container = d3.select('#circle') // First, select the original id
            .attr('x', this.x)
            .attr('y', this.y)
            .attr('height', this.radius * 2)
            .attr('id', 'circle'+this.index); // Now, change the id to make it unique

        this.circle = this.container.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', this.x)
            .attr('cy', this.y)
            .attr('r', this.radius)
            .style('fill', this.color);
    }
}
```

And the html component of AngularD3Donut is:

```
<div id='dountChart'>
    <svg id='circle'></svg>
</div>
```

If you change the id each time, then the original id always will be the next element in the iteration

[image]

[image]

[image]